# Serverless deploying multiple functions

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I've recently updated my serverless project, and I've found that many things have changed in the last few updates.

https://serverless.com/

I don't fully understand whats the correct way to have multiple lambda functions and api gateway endpoints related to the same project. With the old serverless I have every lambda and endpoint as a completely seperate function, this worked pretty well for me.

I can't seem to do this anymore, if I try my second lambda function overrides my first, presumably because my "service name" for both is the same. My service name is the same because I want both rest endpoints in the same API in API Gateway. Since serverless creates the API name based on the service name.

So then I tried to add both functions to the same "Service". this worked for the most part, except that now I need to include my custom role statement for all my functions into the same role (because this one role is now being linked to all my functions). Effectively giving more permissions to each individual function than it should have. The other issue is that all my handler files for the different functions are being put into each functions deployment bundle.

So basically, I'm not sure what is the correct approach to have multiple functions that relate to the same project but are separate in functionality. It used to make sense, now doesn't.

If anybody can give me some pointers please

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand your frustration. I had the same feeling until I looked deeper into the new version and formed a better understanding. One thing to note though, is the new version is not completely finished yet. So if something is completely missing, you can file an issue and have it prioritized before 1.0 is out.

You are supposed to define multiple functions under the same service under the `functions:` section of `serverless.yml`. To package these functions individually (exclude code for other functions) you will have to set `individually: true` under `package:`  section. You can then use include and exclude options at the root level and at the function level as well. There's an upcoming change that will let you use glob syntax in your include and exclude options (example **/*-fn.js). You can find more about packaging here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying.

Not sure how to use different roles for different functions under the same service.. How did you do it with 0.5?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the packaging stuff answered my first concern. I used to assign different roles to different functions using the 'customRole' tag that points the function to the arn of the role. This sits on each function, so you can assign a different role to each to restrict it to only the rights it should have

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a solution for individual iam roles per function as well. I couldn't find a way to do it, but while I was looking through the documentation I found the line: **"Support for separate IAM Roles per function is coming soon."** on [this page](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/), so at least we know they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

The ["IAM Roles Per Function"](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-iam-roles-per-function) plugin for Serverless allows you to do exactly what it says on the tin: specify roles for each function. You can still use the provider-level roles as well:

> By default, function level `iamRoleStatements` override the provider level definition. It is also possible to inherit the provider level definition by specifying the option `iamRoleStatementsInherit: true`

EDIT: You can also apply a predefined AWS `role` at [both the provider and function level](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/).